# Javascript broken in localhost (and Chrome) but OK in Firefox. But not broken at all when uploaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Below is the screenshot of the broken page and the second screenshot is what it's supposed to look like.

[image]

The error for the above is below:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/assets/global/css/components-rounded.min.css 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:4
```

I tried to find this components-rounded.min.ss inside the jquery.min.js, but I did not find any.

So it has error in jquery? But that's the official jQuery, and not something else.

The picture below is what the page is supposed to look at.

[image: in localhost, but viewed in firefox, and it's ok]

Somehow when I uploaded it to my server, it's OK for both Chrome and Firefox. I'm dumbfounded by this. I've tried changing the jQuery, it's still the same.

What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:

Most people ask me to download that *components-rounded.min.css*

But the file do not exists both in the server or in my local. But somehow it's working when I viewed the page in the server. And that components-rounded css file also does not exists in my server.

Yep, I've cleaned up my browser cache. Twice.

Comment: Clear your Browser cache. It won't try to load that file if it's in the memory already.

Comment: @jedifans - no there isn't

Answer (score 0):

Download that file from your server and place it in the right file locally. Ideally commit it to version control too :)

Comment: The files does not exist. In my server or locally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the `css` file `components-rounded.min.css` and save it locally in your `css` folder.

Comment: Nope. the file does not exists. Both in my server or locally.